# Can not retrieve data from a ODBC connection to DB2 iSeries

Tags: .net, odbc, db2

I've been trying to connect to a DB2 database on AS/400  for days! After I installed the IBM System i Access for Windows client I could create an ODBC data source from visual studio and when I click on "test connection" it is sucessful. However, executing a simple SELECT statement results in an infinite wait since database doesn't seem to respond to it.
The code I'm using to connect and query is:

```
            OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(@"Dsn=TEST1;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypwd;DBQ=mydb2");
            conn.Open(); 

            try
            {
                string cmmTxt = query;
                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmmTxt, conn);
                OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dset);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
```

The line where the execution stops responding is "da.Fill(dset);". BTW I'm using visual studio 2010 and I don't see any error message, but the code never finishes "waiting" after that line. Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your 'simple' SELECT statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but can you try using a data reader and see if that gives you better results?

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(@"Dsn=TEST1;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypwd;DBQ=mydb2");
string SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable";
using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand(SQL, connection, null))
{
    using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var value = reader["MyColumn"];
        }
    }
}
```

Second, are you sure that your query will return in a reasonable amount of time?  Do you have some tool which lets you run queries directly against the database (I'm not familiar with DB2, not sure if there is such a thing).  Or is there a "profiler" that lets you "peek" at the database queries as they come in?

Since you don't show your query, I wonder if it's a very long-running query.  How long did you wait for the query to return?

John

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. My original query was SELECT * FROM MYTABLE, where MYTABLE is a table recently created and filled with 1 row. I have tried to query this database using visual studio server explorer with the same results (a long waiting) and also I tried the code you posted, this time the line where the execution stops at is  "using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand(SQL, connection, null))" . I have noticed something else, when I click on visual studio option "verify SQL syntax" an error message displays "This command is not supported by this provider"

Comment: I found this thread:  http://groups.google.com/group/ibm_db/browse_thread/thread/ed68b178cdbee4ea?pli=1 which indicates that you need to configure something called DB Connect.  Have you done that?

Comment: I think DBConnect is like an alternative software to connect to db2 iSeries. I installed i Access for Windows instead but I guess I'll have to try it cause I still have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Setting LONGDATACOMPAT flag as 1 in the connection string  worked for me.

```
[C#]
OdbcConnection con =
  new OdbcConnection("DSN=SAMPLE;UID=uid;PWD=mypwd;
  LONGDATACOMPAT=1;");
```

see the full explanation in the URL below

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0011829.html